# Netbeans: Auto Format - Prevent Space Formatting on Variable Assignment

Tags: netbeans, ide

I prefer formatting assignments like this:

```
$foo          = $bar;
$long_foo     = $bar;
```

instead of this:

```
$foo = $bar;
$long_foo = $bar;
```

However the latter is being used by Netbeans when using auto format.
Anyone knows how to fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's been 3 years since this question has been posted but I think it is very useful, so I should answer this question. I've found **[one website](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/formatting_group_multiline_alignment_added)** that it seems right to your question.

> In Alignment category there are new properties for Group Multiline Alignment - Assignment and Array Initializer.

[image: Formatting Options]

Comment: It's link only answer, you should avoid posting such answer which is having link only. Instead post a comment over the thread for the reference.

Comment: Thanks, glad to know this feature exist!

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I'd like to know how to prevent Netbeans (and maybe other editors) from reformatting specific parts of my code... for example, Netbeans does a pretty bad job at formatting chained method calls with nesting. It totally ignores the nesting level when calculating the indentation width.

Comment: I agree, dont use the auto formatter is you have chained appends such as (StringBuilder) sb.append("").append("");   It igrores all manual formatting and lups everything into one big line.  Yuck

Answer (score 0):

I think the short answer is:  you can't.   There are a few things you can configure as listed onhttp://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/editor-codereference.html but for the most part there is not a lot of configuration.

Have you looked at 3rd party plugins?
I used one for eclipse called Jalopy http://jalopy.sourceforge.net/ that I read somewhere might be supported for netbeans...  Worth investigation